# Why does refreshApex not execute when called imperatively?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Have have a button on a LWC, when clicked calls the following method:

```
handleSubmitForApproval() {
    console.log('Submit for Approval clicked.');
    submitForApproval({recordId : this._agreementId})
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Submit for Approval returned.');
            return refreshApex(this.getAccountResult);
        });
}
```

The `submitForApproval` server method just submits a record for approval. This works fine.I can also get the message `Submit for Approval returned.`. However, my 'getRecord' wire 'getAccountResult' is not being refreshed.

Why does refreshApex not execute when called imperatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does get called. But the callback function related to `this.getAccountResult` is executed only if there is change in any of the fields of object in your client machine and database. So, if you have console logs, you will see the logs in `this.getAccountResult` callback function only if there is change in client record vs database record

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As the object returned from the wire is cached it is read-only. I thought the whole point of `refreshApex` is to force a refresh of your data, regardless if it has changed or not. Any suggestions on how I might force a refresh from the client-side?

Comment: What it is doing is absolutely fine. Why do you want the function to run when there is absolutely no change? that leads to performance issues.
For testing it, you can change some field value (which you are querying in getRecord) in database in developer console and immediately invoke refreshApex in UI and check

Comment: I have a chain of events that sets up the UI based on server updates. I decided to just update the UI on the client side (simulate the refresh) as the result will be the same as a server or page refresh. I agree with your point about performance.